# Program that prints whether the first input number is greater than the second input number

Tags: python

I’m trying to help my son with python and I’m not much help.

The task is - write a python program that asks the user to enter two numbers (`number1` and `number2`) and then prints whether the first number is greater than the second number or prints the second number is bigger than the first number

I wrote:

```
Number1 = input(“please enter your first number”) 
Number2 = input(“please enter your second number”)
```

Then I’ve crashed out ☹️

Comment: Is this the whole program? There's nothing there to make it crash. Do you mean it exits? There's nothing more for the program to do after you've inputted an answer for the two questions

Comment: I want the program to tell me that the imputed number 1 is either greater or smaller than the second number imputed. 

I’ve tried If number1 <=45:  print (“ number1 is less than number2”)

Comment: You seem to have missed one of the first parts of the tutorial: [`if` Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Number1 = int(input('please enter your first number')) 

Number2 = int(input('please enter your second number'))

if Number1 > Number2:
    print('Number1 bigger than Number2')
elif Number1 < Number2:
    print('Number1 smaller than Number2')
else:
    print('Number1 equal to Number2')
```

Answer (score 1):

The Mo Huss's answer is the simplest and most effective solution to this problem. In addition, you may also want to put an exception catcher like this:

```
try:
    Number1 = int(input('please enter your first number')) 
    Number2 = int(input('please enter your second number'))
except ValueError:
    print('please provide numbers')
```

Basically, this prevents your application from crashing if you input a string, or nothing at all, since Python won't be able to convert that to a number (via the int() function) and therefore would raise a ValueError exception.

You may even complicate things a little by looping over the code until you input two valid numbers, but I think that goes beyond the scope of your original question.

Cheers!

PS: Also, you mentioned that your program just crashes. Does that mean it crashes by default (i.e., you try to run it but it crashes) or do you do something specific for it to crash?

As you've been told already, there seems to be nothing that would make the code crash. Maybe check that the double quotation marks (") are formatted properly; if you use certain text editors it will change from a default, vertical double comma to curly ones (for instance, Microsoft Word does this, but that's not a suggested code editor in the first place, for many reasons, including this one).